# Access violation reading location using WndClass

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I have one problem, using this code:

```
BOOL RegisterApp(HINSTANCE hInst)
{
    WNDCLASS wc;

    wc.style         = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wc.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra    = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra    = 0;
    wc.hInstance     = hInst;
    wc.hIcon         = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hCursor        = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(GRAY_BRUSH);
    wc.lpszClassName = szClassName;
    //

    //
    return RegisterClass(&wc);
}
```

When i'm trying using `&wc`, i have this error:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x763adf81 in lab3.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xcccccccc.
```

Please help me, what i need to do with this?

Comment: You don't set `lpszMenuName`. You should set it to NULL;

Comment: Better yet, always initialize all data. Structures can be zero-initialized in C++: `WNDCLASS wc = { 0 };`.

Answer (score 5):

You have not initialized all of the data members of wc.

Refer [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633576(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633576%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)